# Why instrumented Spring REST Controller thread waiting on a lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, eclipselink, spring-restcontroller

We have a Spring Boot Application (v2.0.7) using REST Controller and JPA with EclipseLink. In one of the tests we made the DB not accessible, which in a few minutes led to the app not responding to REST requests at all.

A Thread Dump was taken which reveals the following:

1) 4 Threads are stuck on socket.read() while executing OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(). They will get unstuck after a few minutes (presumably DB timeout). This is understandable.

2) ~180 Threads are in WAITING (parking) state. They execute a RestController method via Spring instrumented proxy, which lead to them being parked waiting on a lock. Here is an example:

```
"qtp68159840-600" #600 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe54400c800 nid=0x371d waiting on condition [0x00007fe5246c8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000070727d808> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:967)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1283)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:489)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.xxx.XXXApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7601a28.getSomeValue(<generated>)
...
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
...
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:873)
...
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
...
```

Looking at this line in the stack trace:

```
com.xxx.XXXApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7601a28.getSomeValue(<generated>)
```

where `com.xxx.XXXApiController` is our REST Controller, and `getSomeValue()` is one of its methods, we conclude that REST requests actually do get to the Controller (the cglib-instrumented version of it), but then this instrumentation decides that it should make it park and wait on a lock. Actually, the reference to the lock from this particular thread (e.g. `0x000000070727d808`) is mentioned only once in the trace and not found anywhere else in the thread dump.

**Can anyone help understand why does it make it wait on the lock and what is this lock?**

The Controller has an `@Autowired` field that is a JPA Repository. Possibly, because of this `@Autowired`, instrumented code of the Controller somehow "knows" there is a problem with the DB connection and locks the Jetty threads? Can anyone clarify how this mechanism works?

### UPDATE

Providing Controller code as requested in the comments (tried to show only the relevant parts).

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-04-17T09:25:33.309Z[GMT]")
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class XXXApiController implements XXXApi {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private DaoService daoService;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public XXXApiController(ObjectMapper objectMapper, HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('db-read')")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Something> getSomething(
            @ApiParam(value = "", required=true, allowableValues = "a,b,c,d") @PathVariable("keyType") 
            String keyType, 

            @ApiParam(value = "keyValue for a given keyType", required=true) 
            @PathVariable("keyValue") 
            String keyValue,

            @ApiParam(value = "The troubleshooting optional parameter", allowableValues = "x,y,z") 
            @Valid @RequestParam(value = "from", required = false) 
            String from) {

        request.setAttribute(METHOD, "getSomething");
        if (keyValue == null|| keyValue.length() == 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if (from != null && from.equals("cache")) {
            result = daoService.getSomethingFromCache(keyValue);
        } else {
            result = daoService.getSomethingFromDb(keyType, keyValue);
        } 
        ResponseEntity responseEntity;
        if (routingInfo != null) responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        else responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return responseEntity;
    }

   ...
}


@Component
@Controller
public class DaoServiceImpl implements DaoService {

    @Autowired
    private SomethingRepository somethingRepository;

    @Override
    public Something getSomethingFromCache(String name) {
        String somethingStr = getFromCache(name);
        if (somethingStr != null) {
            return convertSomethingFromCache(somethingStr);
        }
        return null;
    }    

    @Override
    public Something getSomethingFromDb(String keyType, String value) {
        return createSomething(somethingRepository.findByKey(value));
    }

    ...
}


@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SomethingRepository extends JpaRepository<Something, Long>, SomethingService {
    @Query("select t from Something t where " +
            "(:x is not null and t.x = :x) or " +
            "(:y is not null and t.y= :y)")
    public List<Something> findByFilter(
            @Param("x") String x,
            @Param("y") String y,
            Pageable request);
}
```

Comment: Show the controller code. The lock seems to be related to something in Spring Cloud (`org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean`) that you haven't mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks @rainerfrey, you got me going in the right direction. The only reference to Spring Cloud comes from RefreshScope annotation, which I didn't notice Controller was annotated with. 
It got occasionally copy-pasted from another class, and shouldn't be here. You can add an answer and I'll accept it.